# VB.NET WebBrowser Take textarea value

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I can not take the value from a web textarea
the code is as follows

```
<input type="text" name="ID1" id="subject" size="20" value="TEST1" />

<input type="text" name="ID2" id="subject" size="20" value="TEST2" />
```

I want to insert the value TEST1 and TEST2 in a vb.net form
and show messagebox with the value 
thanks I hope you can help me, I beg your pardon for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

The name field does not really matter.  You want the id field to be different.  You can keep them the same if you want.  Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="ID1" id="ID1" size="20" value="TEST1" />

<input type="text" name="ID2" id="ID2" size="20" value="TEST2" />
```

I'm not sure what you mean by show messagebox.  Are you talking about a javascript `alert()` call?

---

Also, note this is not actually VB.NET.  The code you have posted is just html.  If you want to interact with the values on the serverside you would need code that looks something like this in your aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox id="id1" columns="20" text="Test1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I refer to your browser, maybe I explained evil
I want to take the values of the textarea
example
I have a form with a textbox in vb.net
and I want the textbox there is the value of the textarea
understand?

Comment: I tried with Textbox1.text = Webbrowser1.document.all("ID1").tostring but does not work

Comment: Ok, I'm totally lost.  You have a vb.net form with a textarea and you want to get the value of another control on the web page which is an input of type text?  I'm guessing you want to do this when the user types on the page?  Why not just make the original control a textarea?

Comment: I resolved, thx Hogan.
the code that allows me to take the value of a textarea is Example:
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.All("ID1").GetAttribute("value")

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim HtmlElementcoll As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcoll
            ' Check the attributtes you want
            If elem.GetAttribute("name") = "status" Then
                'Check even the text if you want
                ' If elem.InnerText = "Sign In" Then
                'Invoke your event
                elem.SetAttribute("value", "hey")

                'elem.InvokeMember("click")

                'End If
            End If
        Next
```

you can fill a textbox without an id like this i have  used getAttribute method to get the name of the field and setAttribute to set the value of the textbox.